# Error while installing updates in Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: apt, update-manager

I have this error while installing updates in Ubuntu 18.4. I have followed the troubleshooting steps mentioned earlier but I still get the same error

```
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                      dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.15.0.43.45); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-43
 linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### Can you help on this regard.

here is the output of the df-h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            915M     0  915M   0% /dev
tmpfs           189M  3.3M  186M   2% /run
/dev/sda6       273G   99G  160G  39% /
tmpfs           945M   28M  917M   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           945M     0  945M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       21M   21M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/25
/dev/loop2      4.8M  4.8M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/171
/dev/loop4      1.7M  1.7M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/154
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/69
/dev/loop1      411M  411M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform/58
/dev/loop5      1.5M  1.5M     0 100% /snap/notepad3/91
/dev/loop6       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6130
/dev/loop7      6.4M  6.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-clocks/85
/dev/loop8      203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/768
/dev/loop10      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop12     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop13     411M  411M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform/74
/dev/loop11      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/536
/dev/loop9      131M  131M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/4
/dev/loop14     2.0M  2.0M     0 100% /snap/notepad3/94
/dev/loop15      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/594
/dev/loop16      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/677
/dev/loop19     4.8M  4.8M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/184
/dev/loop18     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/770
/dev/loop22      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6259
/dev/loop21      91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop17     3.4M  3.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
/dev/loop20     410M  410M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform/56
/dev/loop23     136M  136M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/9
/dev/loop24      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop25      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop27     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop26     4.8M  4.8M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/173
/dev/loop28     196M  196M     0 100% /snap/vlc/555
/dev/loop29     1.5M  1.5M     0 100% /snap/notepad3/89
tmpfs           189M   16K  189M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           189M   40K  189M   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

output of sudo apt install  -f
[sudo] password for seshagiri:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.15.0-43 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't 
find an archive for it.
```

---

I did try other things to resolve the issue

### I tried to remove and install the packages using the following commands commands: remove - remove packages and autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages update - update list of available Configuration options apt.conf(5).

Hello N0rbert I tried the following steps again still I get the same error I am unable to fix this issue.

sudo dpkg --configure -a [sudo] password for seshagiri: dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-43 (--configure): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic: linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic depends on linux-headers-4.15.0-43; however: Package linux-headers-4.15.0-43 is not configured yet. – Seshagiri Rao Jan 30 at 12:57   
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: linux-headers-4.15.0-43 linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic –

### I am really worried, I don't want reinstall the Operating system. My apologies.

I still get the same error message "Package operation failed

### The installation or removal of a software package failed". any solution to this problem  is a big welcome.

There was no issue with the first command.
I just ran the following command and this is the output I get

apt-get remove --purge linux-headers-4.15.0-43

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-43* linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 89.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 205737 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic (4.15.0-43.46) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-43 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-43
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

### You are correct, my system keeps freezing every time I have some or the other updates to install.

I searched again over the net and found the following set of commands has resolved the issue.thanks guys

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  linux-headers-4.15.0-43.
apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-43

Comment: Please add output of `df -h` and `sudo apt install -f` to the question.

Comment: tmpfs           189M   16K  189M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           189M   44K  189M   1% /run/user/1000

Comment: Please add such information inside question - not in comments! Consider to remove all comments and add info to question.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove package info from apt cache with `rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*`
2. run `apt-get remove --purge linux-headers-4.15.0-43`
3. run `apt-get update`
4. run `apt-get -f install`

Let me know what state  you're in. might be there was some issue when you have downloaded the package earlier.